# SWIFTUI: Dismiss view on button click using environment presentation model when I have a init declaration

Tags: swift, xcode, environment, init

So I want to do that, the easy thing is to use @Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode. But I have INIT() declaration in my view and I don't know how to put Environment var inside it, to use it in body view.

It is possible to use it? and how I declare it inside a init func?

my init:

```
     var model: ResponseModel
   @State var operacion: String
    @State var cliente: String
    @State var usd = ""
@State var ars = ""
@State var tasa = ""
    @State var idd = ""
    

    
    init(model: ResponseModel) {
        self.model = model
        self.operacion = model.operacion ?? ""
        self.usd = model.usd ?? ""
        self.ars = model.ars ?? ""
        self.tasa = model.tasa ?? ""
        self.cliente = model.cliente ?? ""
        self.idd = model.id ?? ""
       
        
        }
```

if I don't put the enviroment var inside init declaration, I will have a build error

thanks

Comment: why do you want to add the enviroment in the init method ? can you please share more code. I can't understand the use case

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise `operacion` and `cliente` before using self.

You can either do this as with the other state properties. Like this:

```swift
@State var operacion: String = ""
```

But if the value is to be changed in the init, it is better to use the following method.

Or you initialise these variables in the init. Since they are propertyWrappers, it looks special as follows:

```swift
init(model: ResponseModel) {
    self.model = model
    self._operacion = State(wrappedValue: model.operacion ?? "")
    // ...
```

Here is a complete working example:

```swift
struct Test: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var model: ResponseModel
    
    @State var operacion: String
    @State var cliente: String
    @State var usd: String
    @State var ars: String
    @State var tasa: String
    @State var idd: String
    
    init(model: ResponseModel) {
        self.model = model
        _operacion = State(wrappedValue: model.operacion ?? "")
        _cliente = State(wrappedValue: model.cliente ?? "")
        _usd = State(wrappedValue: model.usd ?? "")
        _ars = State(wrappedValue: model.ars ?? "")
        _tasa = State(wrappedValue: model.tasa ?? "")
        _idd = State(wrappedValue: model.id ?? "")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hallo World")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be very careful when making assignment statements for `@State` property wrapper in the initialiser. As in your case, it's NOT _initialisation_, but _assignment_ as the `@State` variables are already _default initialised_. The behaviour of this assignment is not clearly defined, usually it will have no effect. According the docs "You should only access a state property from inside the view’s body" may indicate that there's more behind the scenes, even though it leaves room for interpretation, and people experience "expected" behaviour as well.

Comment: Okay. Which part do you mean exactly?

Comment: For example, take a look at `idd`: there is the var declaration with default initialisation: `@State var idd = ""`, and in the `init` function you assign it `self.idd = model.id ?? "" `. What happens in the assignment is not clearly defined. A short playgrounds shows that, mostly, the assignment is ignored and the `@State` value  retains the value set in the default initialiser. You can omit the default initialisation and thus making the assignment statement in the init the "initialisation" (which works with current Swift).

Comment: The answer works perfect. @CouchDeveloper Still don't understand perfectly what you mean. could you explain with an example of correct declaration and assignment? I want to improve as much as possible my code. thanks!!

Comment: @JuanOrrequia Please look at this gist: [gist](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/ebaff1befa9ad2b0210366c4889393b1). It has a screen shot showing that you NOT get what you would normally expect. You may want to execute it in your Playground. Note that the behaviour is not defined, and _sometimes_ you get the "expected" behaviour. There's nothing worse than having to deal with code that works "sometimes".

Comment: @CouchDeveloper im experimenting that issue with the var idd.  you show me the wrong way to declare vars and assignment. but in your example, what is the correct way to declare them?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper You are right. I have adjusted my answer. Is it better now? Thanks for the hint!!!

Comment: I have to add, that what we assume as "expected" behaviour is actually wrong ;) What we need to fix is our mental model what a SwiftUI view actually is. The best source to start is here [Demystify SwiftUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw-NR6tEV3o)

Comment: Johannes, to answer your question: the short version is, you should not initialise or assign `@State` variables from within the `init` function of the view. If you need to pass values from "outside", either use `let outsideValue` within the view (which makes a copy) or pass it as a `Binding` parameter in the `init` function. Only use `@State` variables when you can initialise them without depending on "outside" values. Also note, since `@State` is regular propertyWrapper you can do everything what is allowed to for a PW, but it might be dangerous or has no effect when it's a `@State`.

Comment: I found an article on medium, which explains exactly the problem what we get when we have views with an initialiser which takes a parameter which is used to initialise a `@State` variable: https://medium.com/device-blogs/all-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-state-in-swiftui-7314d0c51318. Or another problem described here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649438